# iPhone: How to set the application badge, when the app is closed/in background?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, background, push-notification

is it possible to set the application badge, while the app is in background mode or even closed? I haven't found anything, yet.

[image: Application Badge]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From within your application you can use the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property of `UIApplication` to set the badge number:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

If you want to change the badge without the user launching your app, you need to use the push notification service. The [Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) should have all the info you need.

Comment: add to your answer (if you think it proper addon), that @Stefan also can use [Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible via push notifications (as you've tagged) but bare in mind that if the user has disallowed push notifications it won't work.

To update the badge number via push, you need to include the following in your payload:

```
"badge" : 23
```

For more info about the payload, see [this apple doc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

Comment: Ok, that is what I hoped :-) At least there is a way to set the badge without having the app running.

Answer (score 0):

I was having difficulties with my app badge number which was being set as the accepted answer states.

I found using this subtly changed code worked better:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
```

Might be worth a check if you are having issues with your badge number

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use push notification you can schedule a local notification to do this. This won't work if you force quit the application though.